# How to use radio buttons for each row of a query

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, radio-button

I have radio buttons for each row of a query. I don't know how to create their names, so that for each row of a query, radio buttons could be checked. Now I can check only one radio of all, but not only for each query row.
I'm using Codeigniter. That's my view:

```html
?php
echo validation_errors();

foreach ($question as $row)
{
    echo form_open();
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo "$row->question";
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>";
    
    $data=array(
        'name' => 'answer',
        'value' => '1'
    );
    
    echo form_radio($data);
     $data=array(
        'name' => 'answer',
        'value' => '2'
    );
    
    echo form_radio($data);
    $data=array(
        'name' => 'answer',
        'value' => '3'
    );
    
    echo form_radio($data);
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo form_submit($data);

    echo form_close();
```

My query in model, which returns this result is:

```html
public function survey_show() {
       
        $this->db->select('question_id, question');
        $this->db->from('questions');
        $result=$this->db->get();
            return $result->result();
    }
```

```html
public function survey_fill() 
    {
        if (null !==($this->input->post('submit'))) {
          $date = new DateTime("now"); 
        
        $data = array(
            'user_id'=>$this->session->userdata['user_id'],
            'question_id'=>$this->input->post('question_id'),  
             'answer'=>$this->input->post('answer_1'),               
            'created_at'=>$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        );

        $this->db->insert('survey_answers', $data);
```

Comment: Does $row contains id of the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't  know your HTML is OK Or Not. 
But this will solve your problem

```
foreach ($question as $key=>$row)
    {
        echo form_open();
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo "$row->question";
        echo "</td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>";

        $data=array(

            'name' => 'answer['.$key.']',//or this 'name' => 'answer_'.$key,
            'value' => '1'
        );

        echo form_radio($data);
        $data=array(
            'name' => 'answer['.$key.']',
            'value' => '2'
        );

        echo form_radio($data);
        $data=array(
            'name' => 'answer['.$key.']',
            'value' => '3'
        );

        echo form_radio($data);
```

But remember use one of them for all `'name' => 'answer['.$key.']',` or   `'name' => 'answer_'.$key,` Don't combine both.

Comment: How can I access radio buttons  in my model, to insert them in DB? I use them in this way: 'answer'=>$this->input->post('answer'). But now how could I access them?

Comment: if you use this `answer['.$key.']` get all answer inside a variable like `$answers=$this->input->post('answer')` `$answers` is the array of all answers. `$answer[0]` is first selected groups value, `$answer[1]` is 2nd selected answer value. and for others

Comment: I used now second way: $data=array(
  'name' =>  'answer_'.$key,
  'value' => ' 4'
 ); But in my model I write:   'answer'=>$this->input->post('answer_'.$key),   and it does not work, doensn't insert anything.

Comment: `'answer'=>$this->input->post('answer_'.$key),` its wrong. it should be `'answer'=>$this->input->post('answer_0'), `for first answer `'answer'=>$this->input->post('answer_1'),` second answer.

Comment: Yes, but I want to be dynamically. If a question is added, to be insert automatically. In my view I get the questions from my DB in this way: foreach ($question as $key=>$row) - how can I do it dynamically?

Comment: You can do it dynamically.Think it.Otherwise the answer will be too long

Comment: I used it : 'answer'=>$this->input->post('answer_1') but it doesn't insery anything yet, maybe I miss something..

Comment: add your model with the question

Comment: I dont see any line like this `'answer'=>$this->input->post(

Comment: Now I added function for insert.

Comment: how you getting `$this->input->post('question_id')`?

Comment: in my view is: echo "<input type='hidden' name='question_id' value='$row->question_id' />"; but it does not work properly, it inserts only the last question_id independently which question I answer...

Comment: I don't have 20 reputation and I can't chat here. Skype?